# openGL glTranslated one shape into 8 different places

Tags: opengl

This is the image I want to get

[image]

This is the image I had

[image]

```
void display(void){
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    int j=120;

    for(int i=0;i<1;i++){

        glPushMatrix();
        if(i%2==0){
            glTranslated(-i*j,i*j,0);
        }else{
            glTranslated(i*j,i*j,0);
        }
        glScaled(1,1,1);
        draw_ring();
        glPopMatrix();
        glFlush();
    }
}
```

I want my image Translated into this 8 different positions as the image I show, I need help with image Translated part for which Translated image into the right places. Can anyone help me and guide me through the right direction, ThankYou.

Comment: What do you expect a loop from 0 to 0 to do?

Comment: for(int i=0;i<8;i++){}, this is the right one, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do what you want is to use 2 nested loops:

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    int    rows      = 2;
    int    columns   = 4;
    double tile_dist = 120.0;

    for ( int col = 0; col < columns; ++ col )
    {
          for (int row = 0; row < rows; ++ row )
          {
              glPushMatrix();
              glTranslated( col * tile_dist, row * tile_dist, 0.0 );
              glScaled(1,1,1);
              draw_ring();
              glPopMatrix();
          }
    }
    glFlush();
}
```

If you want to draw it with a single loop, then you have to calculate the current row and the column inside the loop. The tiles have still to be draw row by row or column by column. Calculate the row and the column dependent on the control variable (`col = i % tile_x`, `columns = i / columns`)

```
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    int    columns   = 4;
    double tile_dist = 120.0;

    for ( int i = 0; i < 8; ++ i )
    {
          int col = i % columns;
          int row = i / columns;

          glPushMatrix();
          glTranslated( col * tile_dist, row * tile_dist, 0.0 );
          glScaled(1,1,1);
          draw_ring();
          glPopMatrix();
    }
    glFlush();
}
```

Comment: I think I already solve the problem, but your answer is exactly what I did. Very helpful answer, Thank You. But after I finish my image, new resolution issue came out.